# Android In-App Billing Dynamic Product List

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I am currently working a setup for in-app billing on one of my applications. Is there a way to set up purchases without a product list on the Android Market side? Essentially, I want to do what I am allowed to do in most other merchant APIs, send the product name/id/PRICE/etc to the merchant and get back a response from them if the payment went through or not.

I have too many products to manually add each item to the Android Market Publishing area and want to send the user to the in app market request with a custom title, description, and price (most important), and have Android handle that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you can't.

The reason for this is security. Someone could hack your app and add a new product/ change your product prices, but defining them on the market; they would have to hack your app *and* have your login for the android market.