# Dynamic In-App Purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services

This question ([Android In-App Billing Dynamic Product List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739704/android-in-app-billing-dynamic-product-list)) was asked over 3 years ago. Are dynamic in-app purchase items still unavailable to Android?

The reason I’m looking to implement this sort of functionality is because my app features a way for certain users to create their own in-app purchases for others to buy.

It seems like an alternative solution would be to use consumable in-app currency but I’d much rather have a purchase option directly through the Play Store (especially since I’ve seen methods for hacking in-game currency everywhere).

Regardless of the option, I do want to use server-side verification. Might there be a way to add in-app purchases through a server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will suffice, but you can use the [Google Play API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) and [insert](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/insert) new in app billing products that way. All in app billing products for Android still need to be [specified](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html) in the Google Play Developer Console, but at least with the Play API, you can do it programatically.

Comment: This definitely looks promising! I'll update the question as soon as it's implemented. Thank you

Comment: hi @Andy can you give me the detail of how to use this insert product using API . I can't understand in this doc that how I can insert my item dynamically.

Comment: I'm going through with same problem, can you help me or do you have any example for this. @nidhi c0deblooded

Comment: @c0deblooded did you implement this feature?:)

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Nope, I didn't end up adding this logic to my app since I pivoted the design not long after. Definitely seems doable if needed in the future though.

Comment: I will implement it and post the answer. :).

Comment: Hi, I've used this API to insert products to Play Store successfully(its active and visible) BUT only the products that I add via this API doesn't load in the client app when I use the Google Play billing library. Do you happen to know why? Did you also face a similar issue?

Comment: Can you maybe share your experciences with this? @sammy

Comment: @JulianLenz Hi, yes. I've posted a question regarding this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299505/google-play-billing-unable-to-query-certain-products-from-play-console#comment118431707_66299505).

Comment: Beware there are limits to this approach. Google has 1k limit and Apple 10k limit on items created.
Src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391473/maximum-limit-for-items-in-in-app-billing-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 6):

I managed to implement this using a Google Play Api and uploading the products to the playstore dynamically/programmatically.

First I used PHP since I am using Laravel for my backend REST API. It is up to you to choose you own. I will installed the `google/apiclient` library using composer
using `composer require google/apiclient`

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/insert

A sample product could be uploaded as such:

**Step1:** You will need to authenticate to the service. By using a service json file or Auth oath if you prefer. In my case I used the service json file and enabled the Google Play API in my GCP console.

**Step2:** You need an sku(unique) refer to the docs and see the required format

**Step3:** You need to set a Price(micros) you can use https://github.com/Torann/laravel-currency to convert from one currency to another which I used in this case to obtain my currency based on the default currency of the Store(In app products) **NB:** The currencies must match else you will get an error.

**Step4:** You need to set Listings which are basically the title/descriptions under that your app needs for translations purposes

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('service_account.json'));

// You have to add this scope so it knows it is in app billing store
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher');
$service = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);

$body = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_InAppProduct();
$body->setSku("unique_sku_here");
$body->setPackageName('android_app_package_name'); // e.g com.example.in_app_test

//1.00 USD = 1,000,000 Microns.

// Create a new price object 
$price = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Price();
$price->setCurrency('USD');

//Using **torann/currency** library to convert from one currency to another

$new_price = intval(currency("1000", $from = "EUR", $to = "USD", false));
$price->priceMicros = $new_price * 1000000;
$body->setDefaultPrice($price);

// Setting the default language

$body->defaultLanguage = "en_US";
$body->setListings([
                    'en_US' => [
                        'title' => 'Product Title',
                        'description' => "Product Description here"
                    ]
                ]);    

$purchase = $service->inappproducts->insert(
                     'android_app_package_name',
                     $body,
                    [
                      'autoConvertMissingPrices' => true,
                    ]);

$purchase->setStatus(true); // Always set this to mark the product active on the GPlay console.
```

With this you will have a return of a successful product upload.

Cheers. Feel free to comment should you have any blockers, I would be happy to clarify.

Comment: Hi, I've used this API in my Java backend to insert products to Play Store successfully(its active and visible) but only the products that I add via this API doesn't load in the client app when I try to query my products  using the Google Play billing library. The products that I add manually via the console are only visible which is strange. Do you happen to know why? Did you also face a similar issue?

Comment: Can i see how you are getting the products?

Comment: Hi, here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299505/google-play-billing-unable-to-query-certain-products-from-play-console#comment118431707_66299505) with more details.

Comment: Beware there are limits to this approach. Google has 1k limit and Apple 10k limit on items created.
Src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391473/maximum-limit-for-items-in-in-app-billing-in-app-purchase