# Auto insert In App Purchase item from android app using version 3 API

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

[Dynamic In-App Purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493345/dynamic-in-app-purchases) in this answer It says that you can insert the item dynamically.but I can not underestand that how I can do this.

my requirement is : 
Some videos are arrived dynamically during app is open and I have add them to in app managed purchase (It can buy one time). how can I handle them using google's developer api in android.here all items have different prices.

Any Help.

Comment: The bounty is enticing but "**please give me detailed tutorial with code**", seriously?